# VLAN sniffing in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

If I use the following code within the scapy shell, VLAN sniffing works
perfectly.

```
    conf.use_pcap=True
    import scapy.arch.pcapdnet

    p=sniff(iface='enp3s0', count=20, timeout=15)

    if p:
        for i in p:
            i.show()
```

If I used the same code within a python shell (with additional `from scapy.all import *` as first import), the code does not sniff
any packet.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?